# How many slots did Byron era (testnet) have?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-node, testnet, slottime

I was wondering the number of slots the **Byron** era (**testnet**) had or the slot number when Byron finished.

The only info I've been able to find is **systemStart": "2019-07-24T20:20:16Z"** coming from **testnet-shelley-genesis.json**.

( [Calculate timestamp from slot](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/491/calculate-timestamp-from-slot) discusses about the same thing but with mainnet Byron. )

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should you have accepted the answer?

Comment: @gRebel right, done   ✅

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Shelley started at epoch 1, i.e. after a single Byron epoch 0 on Cardano Testnet.

[Byron started on Testnet](https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en/browse-blocks?page=0&perPage=20):

```
epoch 0 ... slot 1031 ... block 1 ... date 2019/07/25 ... time 02:03:56
```

[Shelley started on Testnet](https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en/browse-blocks.html?page=1029&perPage=20):

```
epoch 1 ... slot 21600 ... block 20570 ... date 2019/07/29 ... time 20:20:16
```

**P.S.**

There's also one simple way to check this out. Start downloading a Cardano Testnet DB onto your computer, and, at the very beginning of the process, apply `cardano-cli` command:

```
cardano-cli query tip --testnet
```

But the best solution is to send a request to the IOHK helpdesk.

Comment: So systemStart": "2019-07-24T20:20:16Z" coming from testnet-shelley-genesis.json, what does it mean?

Comment: I don't know what it means. Testnet explorer shows another date.

Comment: How can I know from the info shown in Testnet explorer that Shelley started in slot 21600?

Comment: No way. I saw a hint among 3.5K messages on `cardanoupdates.com`. Just google this phrase – "`Shelley started at epoch 1, i.e. after a single Byron epoch testnet`".

Comment: One more question if you're so kind. When was the slot duration set to 1 sec on Cardano Testnet? At the beginning of Shelley?

Comment: Sorry @kindofdev, I don't know...

Comment: No problem, thank you for your help.

Comment: Travis found out when 1slot-1sec started, https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6955/when-was-the-slot-duration-set-to-1-sec-on-cardano-testnet 
@AndyJazz