# When was the slot duration set to 1 sec on Cardano Testnet?

Tags: cardano-node, testnet, slottime

I'd like to know the exact date when the slot duration was set to 1 sec on Cardano Testnet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little bit of digging. Block **1597133**, created on **2020/07/28 20:20:16** was the first block to use 1 second per slot.

| Epoch | Slot | Block | Created | Delta Next Slot | Delta Next Created | Time Per Slot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 73 | 1598398 | 1597131 | 2020/07/28 20:19:36 | 1 | 00:00:20 | 00:00:20 |
| 73 | 1598399 | 1597132 | 2020/07/28 20:19:56 | 1 | 00:00:20 | 00:00:20 |
| 74 | 1598400 | **1597133** | 2020/07/28 20:20:16 | 20 | 00:00:20 | **00:00:01** |
| 74 | 1598420 | 1597134 | 2020/07/28 20:20:36 | 20 | 00:00:20 | 00:00:01 |
| 74 | 1598440 | 1597135 | 2020/07/28 20:20:56 |  |  |  |

- **Delta Previous Slot** is the difference between the block's slot and the one before it
- **Delta Previous Created** is the difference between the blocks creation date and the one before it
- **Time Per Slot** is **Delta Previous Created** divided by **Delta Previous Slot**

[Page on Cardano Testnet Blockchain Explorer with these blocks](https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en/browse-blocks.html?page=79857&perPage=20)

Comment: great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: From the info in the table I'd say that the first block with 1 sec would be 1597133 because the difference in slots with the next one (1597134) is 20 slots.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer