# How do I set txInfoValidRange on the testnet using cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli, testnet, txinfovalidrange

How does txInfoValidRange get set on the testnet?

I've been made aware that on the Plutus Playground
a piece of off-chain code:
"Constraints.mustValidateIn (from now)" will
set txInfoValidRange (works great).

I'm looking for the equivalent cardano-cli command
for "Constraints.mustValidateIn (from now)",
that will set the txInfoValidRange properly on
the testnet?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options

```
--invalid-before SLOT    Time that transaction is valid from (in slots).
--invalid-hereafter SLOT Time that transaction is valid until (in slots).
```

In you example you would use `--invalid-before $CURENT_TIME_SLOT`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. --invalid-before SLOT worked perfectly!

Comment: I'd upvote both answers, but I only have an 11 reputation - need 15. I'll come back and do it when I get there. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @GaryAlexander Even so, I think you can mark one of those how the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

At the time to build a transaction with **cardano-cli** using the command **cardano-cli transaction build**, you can use the input parameters **--invalid-before SLOT** or **--invalid-hereafter SLOT** where **invalid-before refers** to the time that transaction is valid from (in slots), and **invalid-hereafter** to the time that transaction is valid until (in slots).

Notice that if you don't set a valid range the default will be "all the time".

[image]

You can get this info using `cardano-cli transaction build --help`

An example of this would be the following command (shown by Lars in lecture 3). Check https://github.com/kindofdev/plutus-pioneer-program-iter3/blob/main/code/week03/testnet/grab.sh

```
cardano-cli transaction build \
    --alonzo-era \
    --testnet-magic 1097911063 \
    --change-address $(cat 02.addr) \
    --tx-in 18cbe6cadecd3f89b60e08e68e5e6c7d72d730aaa1ad21431590f7e6643438ef#1 \
    --tx-in-script-file vesting.plutus \
    --tx-in-datum-file unit.json \
    --tx-in-redeemer-file unit.json \
    --tx-in-collateral 18e93407ea137b6be63039fd3c564d4c5233e7eb7ce4ee845bc7df12c80e4df7#1 \
    --required-signer-hash c2ff616e11299d9094ce0a7eb5b7284b705147a822f4ffbd471f971a \
    --invalid-before 48866954 \
    --protocol-params-file protocol.json \
    --out-file tx.body
```

here the tx is invalid before slot 48866954. In plutus:

`Constraints.mustValidateIn $ from $ slotToBeginPOSIXTime def 48866954`

In your case you should use `--invalid-before $CURRENT_TIME_SLOT`

If you are wondering how to get a slot number for Cardano testnet given a **posixtime**, here you have a way to do it.

[How to convert posixTime to slot number on Cardano Testnet](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/7034/how-to-convert-posixtime-to-slot-number-on-cardano-testnet)