# How to calculate the slot time of a given date?

Tags: slottime

I would like to know how to calculate the slot time for a particular date(e.g. 1/1/2023).

Comment: Please, check this: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/7034/how-to-convert-posixtime-to-slot-number-on-cardano-testnet/7035#7035

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the slot length which can be changed. You can't be certain about a slot number for sometime that is a long time in the future.

If you assume you know the slot config then you can use
https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/d637b1916522e4ec20b719487a8a2e066937aceb/plutus-ledger/src/Ledger/TimeSlot.hs#L130