# Diagnosing a POSIXTime discrepancy

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, slottime, time, posixtime

My computer's date command is returning a timestamp wildly different from what testnet wants.

Using [this formula](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/7035/6086),

```
> slotToEndPOSIXTime testnetConf 55047601
POSIXTime {getPOSIXTime = 1651015217999}
```

But on my computer

```
$date "%s"
1649413267
```

This is in seconds rather than millisecond, but what might account for the rest of the divergence?

Answer (score 0):

Cadano timestamps are in UTC and your time is almost certainly local time.

Try setting the timezone:

```
TZ=UTC date "%s"
```

As you figured out, `getPOSIXTime` might be returning millseconds (or maybe even microseconds), whereas the `date` command is returning seconds.

Comment: My computer is set to UTC.
https://www.epochconverter.com/ 
says that 1651015217 is some weeks from now. 
I'm guessing my issue is with some config somewhere, but I don't think I changed anything on my node ... or elsewhere...

Comment: The chain start time is set in the configuration.

Comment: Do you mean `scZeroSlotTime`? What should this number be? Neither the value in the example in the repo (1596059091000) , or the number in the linked SE page are close to the value that seems to work. I found no documentation that this number might be different on testnet to mainnet.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is it. Its the chain start time, so its usually set to current UTC time and then the chain is started.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure I follow. What I ended up doing is in the other answer. I think there is something more fundamentally wrong in my setup. Maybe I'll find out when I move to mainnet 

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be anyone else's problem or if i've done something uniquely strange. But here's what I did.

---

I had two issues with time
The first was with PAB config.
Finding a better estimate of the zero slot:

```
$ echo $(($(date +"%s") - $(cardano-cli query tip ${CARDANO_NODE_MAGIC} | jq '.slot')))
1594369215
```

This implies that my `pab.yaml` config needs to have

```
...
nodeServerConfig:
    ...
    scSlotZeroTime: 1594369215000
...
```

Note this number varies depending on how in sync the node is - but this seemed good enough. It is still weeks different from the example config. Very interested if anyone has an explanation for this.

The second issue was that `mustValidateIn` seems to have both an on-chain and off-chain interpretation which don't necessarily round-trip.
This is a bit of a pain when used in conjunction with the State Machine framework. Adding more stringent bounds in the off-chain code rectifies  this. Perhaps this problem is an artifact of the slot config above being slightly out.